# Redirect to relevant webpage according to user form selection in html

Tags: html, laravel

I've been working with laravel. I have created the form below. I want users depending on their selection to be directed to specific webpages that I have already created (for better understanding, please check my comments in code ()). Routing is ok but I need some help with the form. If possible I need help using only html (no javascript). My code is below. The problem is that the form action redirects to /research for every selection user does.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Please choose department</title>
</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="/research" id="tmima">

  {{csrf_field()}}

    Select:<br>

<select name="Department" id="dpt">
    <option value="0" selected="selection">Select</option>
    <option value="geo">Geology</option> <!--should place /geology page link-->
    <option value="phs">Physics</option> <!--should place /physics page link-->
    <option value="chm">Chemistry</option> <!--should place /chemistry page link-->

</select>

<input type="submit" value="Αναζήτηση Στοιχείων Φοίτησης">

</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this in the controller like so:

```
if (request('Department) == 'geo') {
    return view ('/geology);
} else if  (request('Department) == 'phs') {
    return view ('/psychology);
} else if  (request('Department) == 'chm') {
    return view ('/chemistry);
} else {
    redirect->back();
}
```